# In grails, why do I get a StaleObjectStateException directly after refresh?

Tags: hibernate, exception, data-binding, grails, staleobjectstate

I got code like this:

```
def myObject = MyDomainClass.get(myId)
myObject.refresh()
myObject.myProperty = myValue
myObject.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
```

Despite of the get and the refresh, I sometimes get an "org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)" when the save is executed.

It happens when I start to execute this method concurrently in multiple sessions. But then transaction 1 is **definitely** finished, this code is executed again for transaction 2 and it **still** fails! (I'm using a transaction service to re-execute transactions when they fail due to optimistic locking, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375757/how-to-overcome-staleobjectstateexception-in-grails-service)).

How can that be although I get a "fresh" version from the DB?

Comment: Does `MyDomainClass` have any cascade relationships, like `hasMany` or `belongsTo`? That might be the connected objects that get updated and saved in cascade. What class does StaleObjectStateException refer to?

Comment: MyDomainClass does have hasMany and belongsTo relationships, but the Exception refers directly to MyDomainClass#id.

Comment: @Joe, your DomainClass has the version field? And you need it?

Answer (score 1):

[This forum thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=942461) hints that you might need another Hibernate Session. What if you try a new session for a new transaction, like

```
Book.withNewSession{}
```

Comment: Just tried it, this gives me an org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions

Comment: I believe that means that collection it refers to should be re-read too.

Comment: I also tried to close the session before the withNewSession, which then causes and endless loop in the request... very strange. Maybe you're right about the collection, although I don't even know which collection it refers to. So long I'll go for my nasty workaround ;-).

Comment: 1. I don't see why do you need refresh() immediately after get(). That might be the cause of some `hasMany` collection getting stale. 2. If you wish to explicitly re-read the object, you can evict it from Hibernate cache beforehead: `sessionFactory.evict(MyDomainClass, myId); def myObject = MyDomainClass.get(myId)`

Comment: The refresh() was just an additional measure because get() didn't work... I thought this would make sure that the domain object is really the most current one, independently of caching. This is where I feel that I don't know enough about grails, and I don't know where these things are thoroughly documented. Even the Grails 1.2 book stays on a surface level here. Anyway I'll try using evict() next!

Answer (score 1):

I at least found a workaround - rolling back an empty transaction:

```
myDomain.withTransaction { status -> 
  status.setRollbackOnly()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
MyDomainClass.lock(myId)
```

instead of

```
MyDomainClass.get(myId)
```